# Grouping same values in array and adding

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following in an array $orders.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ORDER_NUMBER] => 0001
            [NAME]         => Customer 1
            [LINE_TOTAL]   => 100.00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ORDER_NUMBER] => 0001
            [NAME]         => Customer 1
            [LINE_TOTAL]   => 300.00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ORDER_NUMBER] => 0002
            [NAME]         => Customer 2
            [LINE_TOTAL]   => 550.00
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [ORDER_NUMBER] => 0003
            [NAME]         => Customer 3
            [LINE_TOTAL]   => 300.00
        )
 )
```

I want to group them by the order number and add the line totals together so final array would look like this. The language is PHP.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ORDER_NUMBER] => 0001
            [NAME]         => Customer 1
            [TOTAL]        => 400.00 // 300 + 100 = 400
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ORDER_NUMBER] => 0002
            [NAME]         => Customer 2
            [TOTAL]        => 550.00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ORDER_NUMBER] => 0003
            [NAME]         => Customer 3
            [TOTAL]        => 300.00
        )
 )
```

If anyone could help that would be great, I've tried a few different things but I'm not getting the result i require.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through the orders and place them under associative indexes based on your ORDER_NUMBER. If one already exists, it will add the new LINE_TOTAL to it.

```
$orders;

$newOrders;

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $id = $order['ORDER_NUMBER'];
    
    if(isset($newOrders[$id])){
        $newOrders[$id]['LINE_TOTAL'] += $order['LINE_TOTAL'];
    } else $newOrders[$id] = $order;
}
```